# how to use mysql lock/unlock

Tags: mysql, locking

I have two questions about MySQL usage:

I installed mysql5.7 by default options.
then I connect to MySQL by MySQL query browser:

1) if I run "SET  autocommit='OFF'", then I use "show variables like 'autocommit';" to check the value, but I still get the result:
autocommit='ON'.

Only if I run "SET **global** autocommit='OFF';" then I can see the value has been changed, why?

2) with autocommit='ON' , I want to lock a table by:

lock tables xxx write

but I can still query this table from another session.

why?

Comment: Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single post.

Comment: If the scenario in the 2nd question were true, then you found a bug in MySQL. My suspicion is that you do not do everything by the book, hence the behaviour. An this has nothing to do with auto commit. Lock tables statement is a non-transactional statement, it commits any open transaction.

Comment: I found it's the client issue - MySQL query browser.   If I change to use MySQL.exe, the issue disappears